# I have installed ubuntu on my laptop who has a broken screen. But I am unable to get display on external monitor

Tags: display

I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop which has a broken screen. By inserting it into another PC. But now I am unable to get a display on the external monitor.

Comment: Details are insufficient to understand what you did and what you've tried so far. What do you mean when you say *"By inserting it into another PC"*? What have you tried so far? You would probably like us to put in some effort to answer your question, so it's only fair for you to put in some effort to ask with enough details to help us help you.

Comment: The basic detail I'd need would be what Ubuntu product/release, but you gave no details. The device itself is also useful; but I performed QA testing on old some old *broken screen* laptops & just used the devices keys to adjust which display was used (internal/external/internal+external-mirror/internal+external/internal-only/external-only etc) with the options varying on device (*thus device/firmware must play a role; not just OS*).  What was available was detectable prior to install (ie. *live* ISOs let you realize how easy it would be)